# How to use selenium to download a "idx" file? (what's the MIME of "idx")

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver, mime-types

I was trying to use selenium downloading files like:
ftp://ftp.sec.gov/edgar/full-index/1993/QTR1/form.idx
ftp://ftp.sec.gov/edgar/full-index/2004/QTR1/form.idx

Those are just internally just plain text files, but their weird extension causes me a great headache. The browser always calls some plugin to read the files, and I don't know what MIME type is "idx"?

After searching all around the web, I think a straightforward way is to set the firefox profile like:

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('browser.download.folderList', 2)
profile.set_preference('browser.download.dir', cachedir)
profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', 'application/pdf, text/plain, application/vnd.idx, application/xml, application/octet-stream, text/html, application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-web, application/rtf, text/richtext, application/xhtml+xml')
profile.set_preference('plugin.disable_full_page_plugin_for_types', 'application/pdf, text/plain, application/vnd.idx, application/xml, application/octet-stream, text/html, application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-web, application/rtf, text/richtext, application/xhtml+xml')
profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force', False)
profile.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting', False)
profile.set_preference('pdfjs.disabled', True)
return webdriver.Firefox(profile)
```

I tried to put almost everything I could imagine on properties "browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk" and "plugin.disable_full_page_plugin_for_types", but none of them seem to hit the target.

Does anyone know what's the right MIME to put on here? Or more generically, how do we know a MIME type of an arbitrary file (note that some file extensions are not standard)?

The full code I have is as below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.alert import Alert
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException

def get_browser(cachedir):
    profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    profile.set_preference('browser.download.folderList', 2)
    profile.set_preference('browser.download.dir', cachedir)
    profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', 'application/pdf, text/plain, application/vnd.idx, application/xml, application/octet-stream, text/html, application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-web, application/rtf, text/richtext, application/xhtml+xml, text/x-mail')
    profile.set_preference('plugin.disable_full_page_plugin_for_types', 'application/pdf, text/plain, application/vnd.idx, application/xml, application/octet-stream, text/html, application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-web, application/rtf, text/richtext, application/xhtml+xml, text/x-mail')
    profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force', False)
    profile.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting', False)
    profile.set_preference('pdfjs.disabled', True)
    return webdriver.Firefox(profile)

def write_content(page_source, file_path):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source)
    form_content = soup.find_all("body")[0].text

    print("getting {}".format(file_path))

    with open(file_path, "w") as f_out:
        f_out.write(form_content.encode('utf-8'))

cachedir = "/Users/voiceup/Desktop"
form_dir = "forms/"
browser = get_browser(cachedir)
for year in range(1993, 2015):
    for qtr in range(1, 5):
        year = str(year)
        qtr = str(qtr)
        url = "ftp://ftp.sec.gov/edgar/full-index/" + year + "/QTR" + qtr + "/form.idx"
        browser.get(url)

        # alert means there is broken file
        # refresh the browser until there is no alert
        has_alert = True
        while has_alert:
            try: 
                WebDriverWait(browser, 2).until(EC.alert_is_present())
                alert = browser.switch_to_alert()
                alert.accept()
                print("alert accepted")
                browser.refresh()
            except TimeoutException:
                has_alert = False

        # manually download the file
        file_name = year + "_" + qtr + ".txt"
        file_path = os.path.join(form_dir, file_name)
        write_content(browser.page_source, file_path)


time.sleep(2)
browser.quit()
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Selenium` is definitely not a tool for the job - it adds a huge overhead to the problem.

In this case, [`ftplib`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html) fits perfectly:

```
import os
import ftplib

form_dir = "forms/"

ftp = ftplib.FTP('ftp.sec.gov', 'anonymous')

for year in range(1993, 2015):
    for qtr in range(1, 5):
        url = "edgar/full-index/{year}/QTR{qtr}/form.idx".format(year=year, qtr=qtr)
        filename = "{year}_{qtr}.txt".format(year=year, qtr=qtr)

        print "Process URL: " + url

        # manually download the file
        with open(os.path.join(form_dir, filename), "wb") as file:
            ftp.retrbinary("RETR " + url, file.write)

ftp.close()
```

When you run the script, you would see the files created in the `forms/` directory and the following would be printed on the console:

```
Process URL: edgar/full-index/1993/QTR1/form.idx
Process URL: edgar/full-index/1993/QTR2/form.idx
Process URL: edgar/full-index/1993/QTR3/form.idx
Process URL: edgar/full-index/1993/QTR4/form.idx
Process URL: edgar/full-index/1994/QTR1/form.idx
...
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried to save the page_source manually. But it didn't work fully because some of those files are large. For "form.idx" files in recent years, the size of the file is around 100 Mbs. It causes loading time-out, and broken files.

Comment: @xjmfel okay, good point. Let's see what other options we have. Why do you need selenium here? Thanks.

Comment: There are hundreds of files and hence not so easy to manually download all of them. Is there other ways to do the job? I use selenium because it's the only way I know to automatically download files. Thanks.

Comment: @xjmfel there are options. Can you provide the code you have so far? I need to see where do you start and what needs to be downloaded, so I can play around with it. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I attached the full code to the original post. I think the logic is pretty straightforward. I defined cache_dir but never use it (because of the problem above). If there is any confusion of the code, please ask me.

Comment: Wow that's truly a much more elegant and pythonic solution! I learnt a lot from your piece of code. Thanks again!